# Overflowing textview without overlaping view components in android

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I want to make a textView on the left, and a fixed sized image on the right,
when the text reaches the end of the image it should start overflow itself
Can I implement it in android xml layout?

Here is an example:

dsadsadsadsadsadsa|================
dsadsadsadsadsadsa|================
dsadsadsadsadsadsa|===SOME IMAGE==
dsadsadsadsadsadsa|================
dsadsadsadsadsadsa|================
dsadsadsadsadsadsadsadsadsadsadsadsa 
dsadsadsadsadsadsadsadsadsadsadsadsa
dsadsadsadsadsadsadsadsadsadsadsadsa
dsadsadsadsadsadsadsadsadsadsadsadsa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this library is  what you want:

https://github.com/JustinAngel/TextViewOverflowing

Comment: awesome thanks! i was looking for text overflowing and couldn't find somethign useful!

Comment: You can search in github if you want to find a library.